# Which ffmpeg command to use convert pngs to video?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have pngs starting from `temp0000.png` and ending at `temp7085.png`.

After reading the [ffmpeg manual](https://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#How-do-I-encode-single-pictures-into-movies_003f) I tried the command:

`ffmpeg -i temp%d.png -i a.mp3 -framerate 60  -start_number 0000 output.webm`

But get the error:

`Could find no file with path 'temp%d.png' and index in the range 0-4
temp%d.png: No such file or directory`

What must I change please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`temp%d` expands to `temp0`, `temp1` ... `temp10` ... and so on.

For temp0000, you need `temp%04d`

and the full command should be

```
ffmpeg -framerate 60 -i temp%4d.png -i a.mp3 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.webm
```

Comment: Thanks. What does  `-pix_fmt yuv420p` do please? And ffmpeg ignored my framerate of 60 and used 24 instead, so my video is out of sync with my mp3. What is the right parameter there?

Comment: framerate needs to go before `-i` as shown in my command. `yuv420p` is the only compatible pixel format for web playback, unlike the pixel format of RGB in the source PNGs.